# Is there a way to speed up this loop?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I need to write this block in more efficient way:

```
    for aci in teta_degree:                     
        for t_degeri in t:
            for x_degeri in x_values:
                resulted_y_values = np.tan(aci) * x_degeri + t_degeri / np.cos(aci)
                result.append([aci,t_degeri,x_degeri,resulted_y_values])
```

By using itertools, I could replace for loop but could not find a way to put resulted_y_values into the related places in the result:

```
result_2 =  [i for i in itertools.product(teta_degree,t,x_values)]
```

Comment: All of these are independent loops. I think something is wrong here. You would probably need to use the iterable from outer loop in one of the inner loops

Comment: @ShikharDua Since I need every values of x_values and t, I put teta_degree in the outer loop

Comment: @PaulRooney you're right about the needless recalculations in each nested loop. But I couldn't see any needless iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulRooney, even he (also me) didn't expect that, his solution i.e. taking the `np.tan` and `np.cos` operations to the outer loop gave serious performance:

```
yeni_süre = time.time()
for aci in teta_degree:  
        tan = np.tan(aci)
        cos = np.cos(aci)
        for t_degeri in t:
            for x_degeri in x_values:
                resulted_y_values = tan * x_degeri + t_degeri / cos
                result.append([aci,t_degeri,x_degeri,resulted_y_values])
print('New: ',time.time()-yeni_süre,'sec')
```

`1.061 sec`

While the old one:

`8.601 sec`

Comment: Another result is to use itertools.product was not fast in this case compared to using only for loops when I discarded resulted_y_values related operations; even slower.